# How To Slide different Pages using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a question i want to slide different pages using Jquery with different designs .

FOr example i have three pages index1.html ,index2.html and index3.html and i want to slides these pages  ?

Comment: I guess you want a single page website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about a single page website:

Here is a working fiddle on what you are talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/X4URc/3/

I used html:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar'>
        <div align='center'> <a class='menu1 menu-item'>Item 1</a>
 <a class='menu2 menu-item'>Item 2</a>
 <a class='menu3 menu-item'>Item 3</a>
 <a class='menu4 menu-item'>Item 4</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        <ul class='content-container'>
            <li class='contents content1'>Content 1</li>
            <li class='contents content2'>Content 2</li>
            <li class='contents content3'>Content 3</li>
            <li class='contents content4'>Content 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-item {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-item:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.menu-item:not(.menu1) {
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.navbar {
    background: black;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 700px;
}
.container {
    background: white;
    width: 730px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content1 {
    margin-left: -40px;
}
.contents {
    padding-bottom: 400px;
    padding-right: 668px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
.contents:not(.content1) {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.content {
    width: 730px;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content-container {
    width: 9999999px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.menu1').click(function(){
    $('.content1').animate({'margin-left' : '-40px'});
});
$('.menu2').click(function(){
    $('.content1').animate({'margin-left' : '-770px'});
});
$('.menu3').click(function(){
    $('.content1').animate({'margin-left' : '-1500px'});
});
$('.menu4').click(function(){
    $('.content1').animate({'margin-left' : '-2230px'});
});
// for more add -730px every time
//If you don't want animations change .animate() to .css()
```

I used a  within a div with overflow hidden and then styled it display: inline;

Comment: http://www.humaan.com.au/ I want something like that

Comment: so you want a slideshow???

Comment: Yes Slide show of whole Page

Comment: Easily done just use my fiddle add some arrows and use my menu items as pagers

Comment: where should i put the page link ??
like i have three pages inex.html ,about,html ,contact.html

Comment: at the bottom of the page

Comment: I mean in your code ??

Comment: In the href of the the menu items soz

Comment: Thankx Dude :) it was really helpful ..
i am trying now. if i need help i will disturb you again.

Comment: and can u please increase my number  ??
some one has rated negative

Comment: have done that can you upvote me?

Comment: no i cannot because i have only 8 reputation.

Comment: find a question and answer it and you might get upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained here. have a look
http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

Comment: That isn't a very good example

Comment: http://www.humaan.com.au/ i want something like that